# How to mirror image/preview coming on front camera in my windows 8 phone app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

My reference for the app is this link . It uses video brush to render the preview.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708750.aspx 
The guy talks about giving mirror experience for front camera but doesnt explain how. Please help, I a stuck on this for a week now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Scale Transform to flip the video brush. Below is an example of flipping a Grid horizontally (what you'd need for a mirror).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Render transform is not available for video brush , Is there a way to flip capture sequence??

Comment: The video brush won't have a render transform, but the video brush is being used as the background for the Canvas in the example. You can transform the Canvas.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
Yes, its perfect Mr. Nigel Sampson, that the grid will flip horizontally, but what about the VideoBrush the image streaming should be flip. Any idea about that.... As there is also ScaleTransform but its not working .... how to do this. plz.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Rectangle 
        x:Name="viewfinderRectangle"
        Width="640" 
        Height="480" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="80,0,0,0">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VideoBrush x:Name="videoRecorderBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="viewfinderTransform" ScaleX="1"
                                        CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
```

When using front camera change `ScaleX = -1` and mirror image problem is solved. However the actual video being recorded is still mirror image. Couldn't find any solution to that :(